# The .round(precision) Ruby method is not working

Tags: ruby, math, rounding, precision

**Problem detail**

My routine is a simple set of equations, the result must yield the result as an array of float elements with a precision of 4 decimals. The problem is that the .round(4) method is not working.

**What I tried**

1. Used .round(4)
2. Used .to_f(4)

My code is as follows:

```
def bar_triang(p1,p2,p3)
  #your code here
  
  bary=[]
  
  x0= [p1[0],p2[0],p3[0]].sum 
  x0t= x0.div(3)
  x0tf = x0t.round(4)
  
  bary=bary.push(x0tf)
  
  y0 = [p1[1],p2[1],p3[1]].sum
  y0t =y0.div(3)
  y0tf = y0t.round(4)
  
  bary=bary.push(y0tf)
  
  p bary  
  
end
```

**Note:** The routine accepts an array of the following shape [p1,p2,p3] in which p1 to p3 are coordinates [x,y]. [p1,p2,p3] is an array of arrays.

What I am expecting? An array of two float elements with 4 decimals of precision.

What I am getting? An array of two float elements with no decimals precision.

**What I want to know?**

1. Why the .round(4) method does not work in the context of my code?
2. How can I use .round(4) within the context of my code in order to make it work properly?

Comment: You have provided the code for the function, which is good, but can you also provide some code that calls the function and the incorrect output of that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not because the `round(4)` not working correctly. It's because part of code:

```
x0t = x0.div(3) # Always return Integer
x0tf = x0t.round(4)
```

I suggest using `/` instead of `div`:

```
 x0t = x0 / 3 # return Float
 x0tf = x0t.round(4)
```

Comment: `x0 / 3 # return Float` : Only if `x0` is a Float. So convert it to a Float first, or use `fdiv`.

Comment: @steenslag or simply change `3` to `3.0`

Comment: Many thanks for your comments chaps!. I solved the pronblem with Harry Train's suggestion